# How to present a modalview on top of other modalview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

Ok, this might be easy..

To present the first view controller modaly :

```
WelcomeViewController *userWelcome = [[WelcomeViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:userWelcome animated:YES];
[userWelcome release];
```

this far everything is fine. But, how to pull a second view controller modaly on this one (in any IBAction)? Do I have to pull in a secondary view controller as the first modal view or is there a more simple solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone would be wondering about this:

If you want to have more than just one View controller pulled in modaly, you have to put your view controller in a new navigation controller.

Easy isn't it?